# Most commands won't do anything if I use the console at my Ubuntu server. Why?

Tags: command-line, console

I've bought a vps server a few days ago, with Ubuntu on it, but I have a problem now. By nearly all the commands I put in I get this error:  : command not found. I am logging in as root. I think this is the Ubuntu version I have: ubuntu-8.04-i386-minimal. (Maybe it has to do with 'minimal'? I really don't know.)

To be more specific, the command I have and try to run now is this,

```
cd ~/mclawl
screen -S MCForge -d -m -c /dev/null -- sh -c 'mono MCForge.exe
exec $SHELL'
```

If I do so, I get this,

`-bash: screen: command not found`

Comment: And the PATH is Ok?  'env | grep PATH'

Answer (score 3):

Servers can be used for multiple purposes. Some just need a proxy and are fine with ssh. Others want to run a webserver and require related binaries. To install `screen`, run:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

If you're interested what applications are installed, run:

```
dpkg -l
```

Optionally, add `|less` after it, so you can use the arrow / page up/down keys for scrolling.